# How to place a div between 2 inputs, vertical alligned

Tags: html, css

How can i put i div between 2 inputs, having same heights, vertical aligned? It sounds simple, and i don't understand why the following code don't work:

```css
input{
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
input:first-child{
    border-right: none;
}
input:nth-child(3){
    border-left: none;
}
#between_inputs{
    width: 10px;
    height: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="min" placeholder="min."/><div id="between_inputs"></div><input type="text" name="max"  placeholder="max."/>
```

Somehow the div is placed above the inputs? What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `vertical-align` to input:

```
input{
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 18px;
    vertical-align: top;/* <<<< this one */
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
}

input {
  width: 35%;
  border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 18px;
}

input:first-child {
  border-right: none;
}

input:nth-child(3) {
  border-left: none;
}

#between_inputs {
  /* flex-grow: 1; recommended, grows and takes the remaining horizontal space */
  width: 10px;
  /* height: 18px; not necessary, flex-items have the same height by default */
  display: inline-block;
  background: Lavender; /* just for demo */
  border-top: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <input type="text" name="min" placeholder="min.">
  <div id="between_inputs"></div>
  <input type="text" name="max"  placeholder="max.">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `vertical-align: middle` for both `inputs` and `div` , and decrease the height of div to make it `17px` so they will be perfectly aligned.

```css
input{
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle
}
input:first-child{
    border-right: none;
}
input:nth-child(3){
    border-left: none;
}
#between_inputs{
    width: 10px;
    height: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A7A7A7;
    line-height: 18px;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="min" placeholder="min."/><div id="between_inputs"></div><input type="text" name="max"  placeholder="max."/>
```

Comment: it is not "perfectly align"

Comment: then what did you call this https://prnt.sc/hff07g

Comment: If i don't change the height of the div to 17px, and keep it on 18px, only adding vertical-align: middle, it seems to be perfectly aligned.

Comment: @user2192013 It's ok if this fits you

Comment: sorry but on my latest version of chrome (62) is like this https://prnt.sc/hff758 that's why I commented